Closing SSE connection causes error in Firefox
I'm building a POC react app, and using sse.js to stream text from my SSE-enabled sever and render it on the page. When all text has been sent, the server sends a special flag called isComplete as part of the message payload, letting the client know that all text has been sent, which I'm handling like so:
const streamClient = new SSE(...);

streamClient.addEventListener('message', (event: EventTarget & { data: string }) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    const { isComplete, messages } = data;

    // ... handling of messages

    if (isComplete) {
        streamClient.close();  
    }  
});

Note above that I use the presence of the isComplete flag to manually close the connection, to ensure that it closes. This works in Chrome, and I even notice that there is a note in the docs for the close method indicating that calling close on an already-closed connection is a no-op:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource/close
However, in Firefox, calling close on an already-closed connection triggers my error handler:
streamClient.addEventListener('error', (event: EventTarget & { source: SSE }) => {
    console.error(event);

    // alert the user there is an issue using a toast, etc. ...   
});

I assume that it's a good practice to attempt to ensure the connection is closed from the client side, and I don't understand why Firefox handles this differently. Should I perhaps not attempt to close the connection here, or elsewhere, from the client side?
